# How to delete a db row in LINQPAD

Tags: linqpad

Total NOOB question. I have been using the new linqpad for about 20 minutes now. Great!

But now i want to delete a row in the db. I am using a EF5.0 connection. I cant seem to find anything in the help files or on the net. The only thing I can find is DeleteOnSubmit which doesnt work with EF (as far as I can see). I have also tried DeleteObject which doesnt work either. This is what I have tried.

```
var co = Companies.First();
co.Dump();

Companies.DeleteObject(co);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be just `DeleteObject(co)` and then `SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: @sgmoore - see the error below. I found another way to delete rows in the database because I don't have time to waste on this. I created a new connection directly to the database. My original effort was trying to delete entities through the context but I have not been able to get that to work.

Comment: You can only get that error if you use Companies.DeleteObject(co). The error should not occur if you call just call DeleteObject(co) (or this.DeleteObject(co) if you prefer).

Answer (score 15):

This is old... and I don't know if/when this was added (probably in response to this exact scenario)… but you can accomplish this (in your given example) as follows:

```
//test the following line to ensure the context doesn't complain about the .First() reference

Companies.DeleteOnSubmit(Companies.First()); 

Companies.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: using `SubmitChanges()` is enough, there is no need call `Companies.Context.SubmitChanges()`, this is in Linqpad 5.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `SaveChanges` on your context (`Companies`) for your row to be deleted.

`Companies.SaveChanges();`

Comment: This error is being thrown:Cannot execute text selection: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DAL.Entities.CompanyEntity>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject' and no extension method 'DeleteObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DAL.Entities.CompanyEntity>' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Comment: .. and linqpad doesn't explicitly expose the context.